# Windows 8 App using COM dlls of Sharepoint gives error “Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Web.Services.dll'”?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, windows-8, windows-runtime, sharepoint-clientobject

I have created a sample app using Windows 8 C# XAML to get site info of SharePoint 2010 using COM Dlls. I have added reference of:

```
    C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\SharePoint Client\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
    C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\SharePoint Client\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
```

but when I build the project it gives me following error:

```
Error1: Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Web.Services.dll' E:\Windows 8 And Sharepoint Example\SharePointCOMApp\SharePointCOMApp\SharePointCOMApp.csproj

Error2: Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a. SharePointCOMApp
```

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your term "COM dlls" confused me at first but then I realized you're talking about [Client Object Model](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21786) not [Component Object Model](http://www.microsoft.com/com/default.mspx).

There are currently [no SharePoint client dlls available for WinRT](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winappswithcsharp/thread/6f3a3803-945d-4765-8964-7e5228d52fd8). Only Silverlight and .NET ones are available for download. Obviously you referenced one of those two and encountered errors because they reference other libraries that are not available in .NET for Windows Store apps (i.e. `System.Web.Services.dll`).

You could take a look at the open source [SharePoint WinRT Client](http://sharepointwinrt.codeplex.com/) library. Depending on what your scenario is, it might work for you.

Comment: Thanks Damir Arh even I realized that there is some compatibility issue. But just want to make it sure.

Comment: Can you help to find one more solution regarding Sharepoint 2010 REST API wit Windows 8 I have posted a question related to it LINK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645268/window-8-consuming-sharepoint-rest-interface-through-formsauthentication