# Window 8 consuming SharePoint REST Interface through FormsAuthentication?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, windows-8, form-authentication, networkcredentials

I have created a sample Windows 8 Application getting SharePoint 2010 list data using REST Apis like _vti_bin/ListData.svc I am using NetworkCredential to access the list its working fine. How can I achieve the same results using FormsAuthentication?
Code for NetworkCredential:

```
 context = new CentralAdministrationDataContext(new Uri("http://<SharePoint_URL>/_vti_bin/ListData.svc"));
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential();
            context.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Actually they have given the article related to Client Object Models usage in SharePoint 2010 but thats not possible in Windows 8 App. Can you provide me the same authentication mode using REST Interface of Sharepoint for Windows 8 Application?